# How to transfer a minecraft world from my ipad to my iphone and back to my ipad

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know how to do this with something like ifunbox, but since my ipad is a school ipad it doesn't work to plug my ipad into my computer and it says that this ipad is owned by another computer. Is there a way I can save worlds with icloud backup?

Answer (score 2):

**Okay, so this is a multi-point answer, well, one thing at a time.**

First of all, you want to know if you can **copy worlds via a computer**. This is doable, even if the iDevice is registered to another PC. Being registered to another PC means you cannot perform an iTunes Sync of the data, but basic iTunes file transfer capability is available (unless, since you say it's a school iPad, they locked it, but that's another affair, and it doesn't have anything to do with the PC you are using). Since you did not specify which OS you are using, I'm gonna provide an answer for the three most used:

**Windows/macOS:**

1. Download and install iFunBox from [here](http://www.i-funbox.com/)
2. Launch it and plug your device in. Make sure you authorise the PC from the popup on the device. If your device does not appear in the program, install iTunes from [here](https://www.apple.com/lae/itunes/download/), run it once then close it. Replug your device if necessary.
3. In iFunBox double click on *"User Applications"* below your device name.
4. Find the *Minecraft* icon, double click it, then browse to `documents/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds`.
5. Folders in here are your worlds, each with its original creation name. You can copy, paste, delete and do whatever else you please with them. This guide is repeatable from step 2 with any Apple device you wish.

**Ubuntu:**

1. Plug in your device and authorise the PC from the popup on the device. An iDevice icon should pop up on the Launcher (left dock bar).
2. Double click the *Documents on [DEVICE NAME]* icon that appeared.
3. Find the *Minecraft* icon, double click it, then browse to `documents/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds`.
4. Folders in here are your worlds, each with its original creation name. You can copy, paste, delete and do whatever else you please with them. This guide is repeatable with any Apple device you wish.

And now about **copying worlds via iCloud**; the answer is: no, you cannot. Simple as that. Even if you run an iCloud backup, it still won't sync your worlds. It's actually not a very good idea to use iCloud as a backup solution anyway.

Comment: @sam make sure you accept my answer if it worked

Comment: Using the method you described, I was able to export a Minecraft world from my iPad and run it from Minecraft Windows 10.
The trick for that was to put all the files into a zip and replace the zip extension with ".mcworld"

Comment: @MerkleGroot Now you don't even have to go through this hassle, you can use the Files app on the device to access game files

Answer (score 0):

An iCloud backup will save your minecraft worlds, I got a new iPad last year and when setting it up I selected the iOS 12 backup from my old iPad mini, and after the backup was done I went into minecraft on the new device, and all my old worlds from my old iPad were there.

Comment: This conflicts with the other answer. Can you expand on this?